# About the crossing over of arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

When I draw a commutative diagram by using the `Tikzcd` I am confronted with a problem: the command `crossing over` does not work at one place of the entire diagram.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning,arrows}
\definecolor{grey1}{RGB}{71,71,71}
\definecolor{grey2}{RGB}{100,100,100}
%\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large, execute at end picture={
\foreach \Valor/\Nombre in
{
  tikz@f@1-1-1/a,tikz@f@1-3-1/b,tikz@f@1-3-3/c,tikz@f@1-1-3/d,
  tikz@f@1-3-1/e,tikz@f@1-3-3/f,tikz@f@1-4-4/g,tikz@f@1-4-2/h,
  tikz@f@1-1-3/i,tikz@f@1-3-3/j,tikz@f@1-4-4/k,tikz@f@1-2-4/l%
}
{
\coordinate (\Nombre) at (\Valor);
}
\fill[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=grey1,opacity=0.3]
  (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
\fill[grey2,opacity=0.3]
  (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- cycle;
\fill[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=grey1,opacity=0.3]
  (i) -- (j) -- (k) -- (l) -- cycle; 
  }
]
  T(\Sigma,X) \arrow[rr,near start,"\text{\emph{free}}"] \arrow[dr,swap,"\pi"]  &&
  \mathcal{C}_{\Sigma} \arrow[leftarrow, dr,"\text{\emph{inclusion}}",sloped,above]& \\
  &T(\Sigma,X)/_{\thickapprox_E} \arrow[rightarrow,crossing over]{rr}[near start]{\text{\emph{free}}} && % Here the command `crossing over' doesn't work after compiling the tex.
  \mathcal{V}(E)  \\
  X \arrow{uu}[near start,sloped,above]{\text{\hspace*{8pt}\emph{determine}}}  \arrow[dashed]{rr}[near start]{\text{\emph{affect}}} \arrow[dr,swap,"{\text{\emph{determine}}}",sloped,above] && T(\Sigma,V) \arrow[dashed]{uu}[near start,below,sloped]{\text{\emph{free}}} \arrow[dashrightarrow,dr,swap,"\pi"]& \\
  & \thickapprox_E \arrow[leftrightarrow,rr] \arrow[leftrightarrow,uu,crossing over]&& T(\Sigma,V)/_{\thickapprox_E} \arrow{uu}[near start,below,sloped]{\text{\emph{free}}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I have pointed out the place at which the `crossing over` doesn't work in the original Tex document demonstrated above. I tried to adjusting the command, but it's still failing.

The output of the Tex demonstrated above is as follows:

[image]

The following picture is exactly what I want to look for. Thanks to the help of @egreg I eventually obtain the final version of the commutative diagram.

[image]

Comment: I want the solid arrow with label `free`  (which connects the term `$\T(\Sigma,X)/\thickapprox_E$` and the term `$\mathcal{V}(E)$`) is crossing over the dashed arrow with the same label `free`.   That's exactly what I want to obtain.

Comment: Okay <-> with the text free and the left head < is missing at the moment!?  Like the arrow below(without text)? If im wrong please add the arrow manually to the image.

Comment: @BobyandbobYes, it's still missing.

Comment: Does `\arrow[<->,crossing over]{ll}[near end]{\text{\emph{free}}}` solve your problem?

Comment: @Bobyandbob It still doesn't work

Comment: Wrong solution or do you have compilation problems with the proposal? Alternativ you can try `\arrow[leftrightarrow,near end,crossing over]{ll}[below]{\text{\emph{your text here}}}`

Comment: @Bobyandbob There is no problem and not any warning after compiling the tex with modification based on your up and up up proposal.

Comment: What doesn't work? Maybe i don't understand your problem right? Could you draw manually missing output on the posted image?

Comment: Draw later the crossing over arrow; that is, reverse the arrow that should go below, drawing it from its codomain.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much! Your suggestion give a real solution to this subtle problem.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I upload the correct commutative diagram into the original question post. You may compare two pictures there.

Answer (score 2):

Draw later the arrow that should cross over:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning,arrows}
\definecolor{grey1}{RGB}{71,71,71}
\definecolor{grey2}{RGB}{100,100,100}
%\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large, execute at end picture={
\foreach \Valor/\Nombre in
{
  tikz@f@1-1-1/a,tikz@f@1-3-1/b,tikz@f@1-3-3/c,tikz@f@1-1-3/d,
  tikz@f@1-3-1/e,tikz@f@1-3-3/f,tikz@f@1-4-4/g,tikz@f@1-4-2/h,
  tikz@f@1-1-3/i,tikz@f@1-3-3/j,tikz@f@1-4-4/k,tikz@f@1-2-4/l%
}
{
\coordinate (\Nombre) at (\Valor);
}
\fill[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=grey1,opacity=0.3]
  (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
\fill[grey2,opacity=0.3]
  (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- cycle;
\fill[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=grey1,opacity=0.3]
  (i) -- (j) -- (k) -- (l) -- cycle; 
  }
]
  T(\Sigma,X) \arrow[rr,near start,"\text{\emph{free}}"] \arrow[dr,swap,"\pi"]  &&
  \mathcal{C}_{\Sigma} \arrow[leftarrow, dr,"\text{\emph{inclusion}}",sloped,above] 
\arrow[dashed,leftarrow]{dd}[near end,above,sloped]{\text{\emph{free}}} & \\
  &T(\Sigma,X)/_{\thickapprox_E} \arrow[rightarrow,crossing over]{rr}[near start]{\text{\emph{free}}} && % Here the command `crossing over' doesn't work after compiling the tex.
  \mathcal{V}(E)  \\
  X \arrow{uu}[near start,sloped,above]{\text{\hspace*{8pt}\emph{determine}}}  \arrow[dashed]{rr}[near start]{\text{\emph{affect}}} \arrow[dr,swap,"{\text{\emph{determine}}}",sloped,above] && T(\Sigma,V) 
\arrow[dashrightarrow,dr,swap,"\pi"]& \\
  & \thickapprox_E \arrow[leftrightarrow,rr] \arrow[leftrightarrow,uu,crossing over]&& T(\Sigma,V)/_{\thickapprox_E} \arrow{uu}[near start,below,sloped]{\text{\emph{free}}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The method with `from=dd` doesn't really work because of the textual labels.

[image]