# Drawing diagram using tikzpicture

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows

[image]

How to draw this picture using tikzpicture? I can draw the arrow diagram but the main problem is that I cannot put say `$\mathfrak b$` under `$U_fin(\Gamma,\Gamma)$`. How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried till now.

Comment: You could use `$\underset{\mathfrak b}{U_{fin}(\Gamma,\Gamma)}$` with `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{amsfonts}`.

Comment: The diagramm is related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374229/124842

Answer (score 5):

I would say this seems a job for `tikz-cd`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{cov}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={30,between origins},column sep={60,between origins}]
& & \underset{\mathfrak b}{\mathrm{U}_{\mathit{fin}}(\Gamma,\Gamma)} \ar[r] & 
    \underset{\mathfrak d}{\mathrm{U}_{\mathit{fin}}(\Gamma,\Omega)} \ar[rr] & & 
    \underset{\mathfrak d}{\mathrm{U}_{\mathit{fin}}(\Gamma,\mathcal{O})} \\
& & \underset{\mathfrak d}{\mathrm{S}_{\mathit{fin}}(\Gamma,\Omega)} \ar[ur] \ar[dd,<-] \\
\underset{\mathfrak b}{\mathrm{S}_1(\Gamma,\Gamma)} \ar[r] \ar[uurr] &
    \underset{\mathfrak d}{\mathrm{S}_1(\Gamma,\Omega)} \ar[rr,crossing over] \ar[ur] & &
    \underset{\mathfrak d}{\mathrm{S}_1(\Gamma,\mathcal{O})} \ar[uurr] \\
& & \underset{\mathfrak d}{\mathrm{S}_{\mathit{fin}}(\Omega,\Omega)} \\
\underset{\mathfrak p}{\mathrm{S}_1(\Omega,\Gamma)} \ar[r] \ar[uu] &
    \underset{\cov(\mathcal{M})}{\mathrm{S}_1(\Omega,\Omega)} \ar[rr] \ar[uu] \ar[ur] & &
    \underset{\cov(\mathcal{M})}{\mathrm{S}_1(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O})} \ar[uu]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As noted in Bobyandbob's comment, you might use `$\underset{<below>}{<above>}$` for this. The following does produce your output (very verbosely and except for the crossing arrows):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {$\underset{\mathfrak p}{S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)}$};
    \node (B) at (1,0) {$\underset{\mathsf{cov}(\mathcal{M})}{S_1(\Omega,\Omega)}$};
    \node (C) at (3,0) {$\underset{\mathsf{cov}(\mathcal{M})}{S_1(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O})}$};
    \node (D) at (2,0.5) {$\underset{\mathfrak d}{S_{fin}(\Omega,\Omega)}$};
    \node (E) at (0,1) {$\underset{\mathfrak b}{S_1(\Gamma,\Gamma)}$};
    \node (F) at (1,1) {$\underset{\mathfrak d}{S_1(\Gamma,\Omega)}$};
    \node (G) at (3,1) {$\underset{\mathfrak d}{S_1(\Gamma,\mathcal{O})}$};
    \node (H) at (2,1.5) {$\underset{\mathfrak d}{S_{fin}(\Gamma,\Omega)}$};
    \node (I) at (2,2) {$\underset{\mathfrak b}{U_{fin}(\Gamma,\Gamma)}$};
    \node (J) at (3,2) {$\underset{\mathfrak d}{U_{fin}(\Gamma,\Omega)}$};
    \node (K) at (5,2) {$\underset{\mathfrak d}{U_{fin}(\Gamma,\mathcal{O})}$};
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
    \draw[->] (B) -- (C);
    \draw[->] (A) -- (E);
    \draw[->] (B) -- (D);
    \draw[->] (D) -- (H);
    \draw[->] (B) -- (F);
    \draw[->] (C) -- (G);
    \draw[->] (E) -- (F);
    \draw[->] (F) -- (G);
    \draw[->] (E) -- (I);
    \draw[->] (F) -- (H);
    \draw[->] (G) -- (K);
    \draw[->] (H) -- (J);
    \draw[->] (I) -- (J);
    \draw[->] (J) -- (K);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]